# Using Tkinter to create a menu for my game

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I need help creating a menu for my game using Tkinter, mainly just a play button. I am using Pygame, if that makes any difference.

```
from pygame import *
import random
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos
        self.bitmap = image.load(filename)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    def set_position(self, xpos, ypos):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos
    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x, self.y))

def Intersect(s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y):
    if (s1_x > s2_x - 32) and (s1_x < s2_x + 32) and (s1_y > s2_y - 32) and (s1_y < s2_y + 32):
            return 1
    else:
        return 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
key.set_repeat(1, 1)
display.set_caption('PyInvaders')
backdrop = image.load('data/backdrop.bmp')
enemies = []
x = 0

for count in range(10):
    enemies.append(Sprite(50 * x + 50, 50, 'data/enemy.bmp'))
    enemies.append(Sprite(50 * x + 50, 100, 'data/enemy.bmp'))
    x += 1

hero = Sprite(304, 400, 'data/hero.bmp')
ourmissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'data/heromissile.bmp')
enemymissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'data/enemymissile.bmp')
sandwich = Sprite(304, 20, 'data/sandwich.bmp')

quit = 0
score = 0
enemyspeed = 4

while quit == 0:
    screen.blit(backdrop, (0, 0))

    for count in range(len(enemies)):
        enemies[count].x += + enemyspeed
        enemies[count].render()

    if len(enemies) > 0 and enemies[-1].x > 590:
        enemyspeed = -4
        for count in range(len(enemies)):
            enemies[count].y += 5

    if len(enemies) > 0 and enemies[0].x < 10:
        enemyspeed = 4
        for count in range(len(enemies)):
            enemies[count].y += 5

    if ourmissile.y < 479 and ourmissile.y > 0:
        ourmissile.render()
        ourmissile.y -= 5

    if enemymissile.y >= 480 and len(enemies) > 0:
        enemymissile.x = enemies[random.randint(0, len(enemies) - 1)].x
        enemymissile.y = enemies[0].y

    if Intersect(hero.x, hero.y, enemymissile.x, enemymissile.y):
        quit = 1
        print "...where mah sammich."

    for count in range(0, len(enemies)):
        if Intersect(ourmissile.x, ourmissile.y, enemies[count].x, enemies[count].y):
            score += 1
            ourmissile.y = 480
            del enemies[count]
            break

    if Intersect(ourmissile.x, ourmissile.y, enemymissile.x, enemymissile.y):
        ourmissile.y = 480
        enemymissile.y = 480

    if len(enemies) == 0:
        sandwich.y += 2
        if Intersect(hero.x, hero.y, sandwich.x, sandwich.y):
            score += 10
            quit = 1
            print "YEEEEE GOT ME MAH SAMMICH!"

    for ourevent in event.get():
        if ourevent.type == QUIT:
            quit = 1
        if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
            if ourevent.key == K_RIGHT and hero.x < 590:
                hero.x += 3
            if ourevent.key == K_LEFT and hero.x > 10:
                hero.x -= 3
            if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
                ourmissile.x = hero.x
                ourmissile.y = hero.y

    enemymissile.render()
    enemymissile.y += 5
    hero.render()
    sandwich.render()
    display.update()

print "You scored", score, "/30"
print "It took you", (datetime.now() - startTime), "to play the game."
```

[Code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xCH0VbVV)

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. Also, why do you want to use Tkinter when you are already using pygame for graphics? Just as a "launcher" for the game? This seems counter intuitive to me.

Comment: I am decently new to Pygame, so I'm not sure how I'd go around doing it with Pygame. And yes, supposedly a launcher.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? there are plenty of code examples online

Comment: I've tried, but to no avail.

Comment: i cannot see any Tkinter code in you link

Comment: I had edited it out so there would be no confusion.

Comment: Here's a start. https://gist.github.com/2802185 See also [#menu](http://www.pygame.org/tags/menu) at pygame

Answer (score 2):

Pygame and Tkinter do not blend. 
Your  UI should either provided by one or the other - You could even do some hacks in a windowed (no full-screen ) pygame application to pop-up transient dialogs using Tkinter, but that is not usual.

It could be possible to present a configuration/game estart dialog prior to running any pygame code, stopping the Tkinter mainloop and starting your pygame.

Otherwise, and for a consistent experience, you should add to your project a GUI that makes use of Pygame for in-game usage. (As pure pygame has no ssupport for buttos, menus, text-entries or such). Check http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui if something suits you.